# How to match value between column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the matches from one column with the other columns in a dataframe. The attribute column is a list. Below is an example:

```
  date        tableNameFrom    tableNameJoin   attributeName
1 29-03-2019  film             language        [film.languageId, language.languageID, film.filmID]
2 30-03-2019  inventory as i   rental as r     [i.inventoryId, r.filmId]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(df['attribute'].values.tolist())
                      .stack()
                      .str.split('.', expand=True)
                      .reset_index(drop=True))
df1.columns = ['tableName','attributeName']
print(df1)
```

And the output I've got:

```
  tableName    attributeName
1 film         languageId
2 language     languageID
3 film         filmId
```

Here desired output:

```
  date        tableName    attributeName
1 29-03-2019  film         languageId
2 29-03-2019  language     languageID
3 29-03-2019  film         filmId
4 30-03-2019  inventory    inventoryId
5 30-03-2019  rental       filmId
```

Any idea what should I do? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create dictionary by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `as` for dictionary:

```
df3 = df[['tableNameFrom','tableNameJoin']].stack().str.split(' as ',  expand=True).dropna()
d = dict(zip(df3[1], df3[0]))
print (d)
{'i': 'inventory', 'r': 'rental'}
```

Add index parameter to `DataFrame` constructor and remove last `reset_index`:

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(df['attributeName'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
                      .stack()
                      .str.split('.', expand=True))
df1.columns = ['tableName','attributeName']
print(df1)
    tableName attributeName
1 0      film    languageId
  1  language    languageID
  2      film        filmID
2 0         i   inventoryId
  1         r        filmId
```

Select only column `date` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) new `DataFrame`:

```
df2 = df[['date']].join(df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
```

And last [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) by dictionary:

```
df2['tableName'] = df2['tableName'].replace(d)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
         date  tableName attributeName
0  29-03-2019       film    languageId
1  29-03-2019   language    languageID
2  29-03-2019       film        filmID
3  30-03-2019  inventory   inventoryId
4  30-03-2019     rental        filmId
```

Comment: Use `df1 = (pd.DataFrame(da['attributeName'].values.tolist(), index=da.index)`

Comment: what if the row doesn't have tableNameJoin, so there are only tableNameFrom and attributeName ? I've tried and the attribute name become table name

Comment: @jesicagu - Not sure if understand, can you explain more? the best sample data with expected output in new question. Thank you.